# ¿Cómo resuelvo el error CS0426 en ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto de ASP con .NET FRAMEWORK estructurado de la siguiente manera:

[image: Explorador de soluciones]

Tengo una página maestra la cual es Pincipal.Master a la cual tengo vinculada mi  Web Forms Default.aspx pero cuando compilo me lanza el error CS0426 en el navegador

[image: Error de servidor]

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Buenas tardes, podrías agregar la estructura de tu proyecto y adicional, en que parte del código te genera el error? Saludos.